# Level of hierarchy on CSS in a legacy application in Ruby

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

One of my clients has one legacy system with a HUGE css (kind of emulating bootstrap).

The problem here is that I want to add bootstrap to the new features. But if I do it the "simple" way, the bootstrap overrides a lot of css tags and my app becomes a BIG mess.

For example, I want to add some modals (i dont have it now on the legacy css) and everything brokes if I just add bootstrap.

Is there a way to make a hierarchy on the CSS loading in Ruby? For example, I just want that the system load the bootstrap elements if it doesnt find anything on the legacy css.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that "if it doesn't find anything on the legacy css" exists. You could add bootstrap before the legacy CSS so the legacy CSS overrides the styles set by bootstrap.

You can also import bootstrap the "advanced" way to only import the components you want instead of the whole framework, if you import 'bootstrap' it will load this file: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss. You can replace that import with the individual imports excluding whatever you don't want.